# Units of measurement for vector grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry

Can anybody tell me as to what the units of measurement are (e.g. meter, kilometer, miles etc) in vector grid menu of QGIS (see attached image)?

I want to make cells of certain sizes in meter or kilometer (e.g. 50 meter, 100 meter, 500 meters etc.) but my coordinates are geographic, which is making it difficult for me to specify the cell size in meters or kilometers.

[image: Vector Grid Menu Box]

Comment: I would guess that's degrees. If you let us know what crs the layer is in someone can confirm

Comment: Yes, these are degrees. The CRS is WGS84 with EPSG4326.

Answer (score 6):

If you take the extent of the layer, it will be in the units of the layer (degrees in your case).

If you take the extent of the canvas or draw a rectangle on the canvas, with a **project** CRS using meters, the unit will also be meters. If the layer has degrees, On-the-fly-reprojection is enabled.

So you don't need to reproject the degree layer before creating a grid in meters.

Answer (score 4):

the parameters are taking the units of measurement from the coordinate system thus your result would in degrees. 
Approach:

- Reproject your files into a projected coordinate system and set the parameters to the desired values

or

- Figure out  which values of degrees represent 500m for example and put that as the  parameter value for example [with this simple calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html)